# ERROR 403 al Subir mi pagina a mi servidor Web

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Buenas con todos, tengo un error 403 (Forbidden), que ocurre cuando realizo una peticion via jquery (ajax) a un php. Lo curioso es que me salta este error cuando intento guardar una etiqueta css en el servidor (background-image:url('')). y no sucede con el resto de etiquetas css.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA en mi servidor local (Wamp server), funciona de lo mas normal, esto sucede solo en el servidor web, lo que me hace decudir que pueda ser algun tema de permisos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA2: Estoy utilizando el sistema de serializacion (JSON.stringify y Base64_encode) para guardar mis datos en el servidor.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Adjunto capturas

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar una captura donde se visualice que el URL que termina en save.php no produce error?. Igualmente una captura donde podamos ver los parámetros que envías cuando produce error y cuando no.

Answer (score 1):

De entrada, la consola de errores te muestra claramente que estás intentando usar al menos un recurso que no existe: 
http://theboxcode.com/local/imgs/sld-der.png

Luego, el acceso al archivo 
http://theboxcode.com/local/controlador/save.php está devolviendo un código de error 403

Verifica tu archivo save.php, los permisos que hayas podido otorgar quizá por medio de .htaccess, a los archivos a los que quieres acceder, revisa el errorlog. Casi seguro que te dirá dónde se encuentra el problema.

Saludos.